# Listen for scroll of iframe that is aded after the dom is loaded (for PDF iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events, onscroll

I am trying to detect when an `iframe` is scrolled.  The `iframe` is added after the dom is loaded.  So far I am only able to detect when the `iframe` itself is loaded, but can't seem to listen for its scrolling.

The domain for `iframe` is the same as the site ...it is just loading a PDF.

**EDIT:** This is working when the iframe contains html content, but not with a PDF.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="pdf-media">
     <iframe  id="pdf-iframe" class="pdf-iframe" src="<?= base_url('/file/item/' .$item['course_id'].'/'.$item['filename']) ?>" style="width:100%; min-height:300px; overflow:" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
```

**JS**

```
function checkIframe() {    
  $('.pdf-iframe').load(function(){
    alert('iframe loaded');

    var iframe = $(this).contents();
    $(iframe).scroll(function () {
        console.log("scrolling");
    });
  });
}



function loadCourse(course_slug){
...    
  checkIframe();
...    
}
```

Comment: Does it work if your iframe contents is html? (enough to show a scroll bar).  Could be because it's a pdf.

Comment: Browsers use different plugins to render pdf. You would need a pdf viewer script to do this probably

Comment: Ahh - it does work when the iframe contents are html.  Is there a workaround that you know of? Thanks